# Can't run VS2010 opencv project from IDE

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, opencv

When I run OpenCV project in debug mode it exit with code 0.

But this run from folder without a problem. Could someone help me.

P.S : This does seem to be a problem with Visual Studio as the program runs without any errors when run from explorer by double clicking.

```
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

#include <stdio.h>
#include<fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    VideoCapture capture;
    Mat frame;

    capture.open(0);
    if (capture.isOpened()) {
       while (true) {
            capture >> frame;
            if (!frame.empty()) {
                imshow("Test", frame);
            } else {
                printf(" --(!) No captured frame -- Break!");
                break;
            }

            int c = waitKey(10);
            if ((char) c == 'c') {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In what way does the program fail?

Comment: Works fine in VS2012 / OCV2.4.4.

Answer (score 2):

exit status of 0 indicates successful program termination, so you don't have a problem.
See e.g. [What is the difference between exit(0) and exit(1) in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944785/what-is-the-difference-between-exit0-and-exit1-in-c-language)

Comment: Problem is not the exit code. Problem is program not running as intended on VS2010 but running normally when run from outside using explorer/cmd.