# A Better Understanding Of Linked List

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm learning C and I'm trying to understand a better concept of a Linked List.
I have a code as an example (I changed it to be like the one i want to understand better).
The code doesnt have any mistakes but again like i said it's to understand it better.
Please have a look at the code first and below the code i'll ask my questions:

Here is the code for my struct and my first function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct client{
char first_name[20];
char last_name[20];
char id;
char reference;
char deposit;
struct client *next; // pointer to the next entry in the clients list
};
typedef struct client new_Client;

/***********************************************************
 * find_Client
 * Finds a place in the list to insert new user
 * Input: User's first and last name, id, reference, deposit
 * Returns: A pointer to teh struct which AFTER we'll insert
 the new struct. NULL if head of the linked-list
 ***********************************************************/

new_Client *find_Client(char *new_last_name, new_Client *head)
 {
    new_Client *prev = NULL; // previous has nothing
    new_Client *curr = head; // current is the head

    while (curr != NULL) //// while the current is not NULL because if it's null it's not head
     {  
      if (strcmp(new_last_name, curr->last_name)<0)
        break;

         prev = curr;
         curr = curr->next;  // pointing to the next node
     }
   return prev;
 }
```

And here is my next function where i usually have a problem understanding

```
/***********************************************************
 * add_new_Client
 * Adds a new client
 * Input: clients details and the address of the list's head
 * Returns: nothing
 ***********************************************************/

void add_new_Client(char *first_n, char *last_n, char *ident, char *ref, char *dep, new_Client **head)
{
    new_Client *after;

    // create new entry
    new_Client *new_entry = (new_Client*)malloc(sizeof(new_Client));    //allocating size of the struct

    if (NULL == new_entry) 
    {
    exit(1); //Q1: does it mean that it terminates?

    }
    else 
    {
    strcpy(new_entry->first_name, first_n);
    strcpy(new_entry->last_name, last_n);
    strcpy(&new_entry->id, ident);
    strcpy(&new_entry->reference, ref);
    strcpy(&new_entry->deposit, dep);
    }
    after = find_Client(new_entry->last_name, *head); // Q2: don't understand this line..
      if (NULL == after) // new head
        {
            if (NULL == *head) // Q3: for adding the first item (when the head is NULL) --> why is this condition necessary
            {
            new_entry->next = NULL;
            }
           else
           {
               new_entry->next = *head;
           }
           *head = new_entry;
       }else
         { //add in the middle
           new_entry->next = after->next;
           after->next = new_entry;
       }

   }
```

Okay so i put my questions in the code itself. They're marked as Q1,Q2 and Q3.
Please let me know if you would prefer i edit on my post and change the questioning methode for it to be easier for you to understand my questions.

Comment: I might suggest going off to write your own code first so that you're not trying to force understanding based off of someone else's logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//Q1: does it mean that it terminates?
exit(1);
```

Yes, the program will exit with 1, [which is interpreted as failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944785/what-is-the-difference-between-exit0-and-exit1-in-c).

---

```
// Q2: don't understand this line..
after = find_Client(new_entry->last_name, *head);
```

here, `after` is a pointer to a `struct new_Client`. The function `find_Client` returns a pointer to a client that was searched using `new_entry->last_name`, and `head` is passed in order to give the search a beginning, somewhere to start.

---

```
// Q3: for adding the first item (when the head is NULL) --> why is this condition necessary
if (NULL == *head)
```

Because when the there is only one element in the list it is alone, that is, it doesn't have a `next` element. If the list size is higher than one, however, the *new node*'s `next` element will point to the head, and the this *new node* will be the new `head`. That is, the *new node*'s `next` element will have the value of the last `head` element, just before it. This is why this distinction is necessary.