# Pointers to Array Elements in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am trying to create a program that prints a random number whenever the user enters "roll", and allows the user to enter "1" if the random number is greater than or equal to 3.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    int randomnumber;
    char diceinput;
    int slotnumber;
    char lettertable[7];
    char *character;

    lettertable[1] = 'l';
    lettertable[2] = 'r';
    lettertable[3] = 't';
    lettertable[4] = 'e';
    lettertable[5] = 't';
    lettertable[6] = 'e';

    character = &lettertable[1];

    printf("Enter 'roll' to roll the dice. Enter 'exit' to quit.\n");

    scanf("%s", &diceinput);

    if (strcmp(&diceinput, "exit")==0) {        
        printf("Now quitting. Thank you, and please play again!\n");        
    }

    if (strcmp(&diceinput, "roll")==0) {        
        srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
        randomnumber = rand() % 6 + 1;
        printf("%d\n", randomnumber);

        if (randomnumber >= 3) {            
            printf("Enter 1 to get the corresponding letter from table.\n");
            scanf("%d", &slotnumber);

            if (slotnumber == 1) {                
                printf("%s", character);                
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

After the user enters "1" the program is supposed to get the letter stored in the letter table[1], an element in the array lettertable. However, when I run the program and enter "1", instead of getting the letter "l", the output is a weird phrase: "lrtete" with an upside down question mark. Can somebody please help me? Thank you.

*Please note that the code shown above is only a revelant section of the unfinished program.*

Comment: diceInput is a char but needs to be an array char diceInput[80]; Don't pass a pointer to diceinput for the scanf you don't need to alter where the array is -- just the data inside the array.

Comment: Please learn how to indent consistently.  It makes it easier to read and understand the code.  Using a one space indent is too small in my view.  SO encourages 4 space indents by mapping tabs to 4 spaces in display; it is a reasonable balance between indenting enough to be clear and not overrunning the line length.

Comment: Also, you print 'Now quitting' but your code does not then quit.  And there doesn't seem to be a loop in there.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
if (slotnumber == 1) 
{
        printf("%c", *character);
}
```

Also as pointed by [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) your code does not quit for `if (strcmp(&diceinput, "exit")==0)`. You should use [exit(0)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2425223/2455888) to quit;

```
 if (strcmp(&diceinput, "exit")==0) 
 {
      printf("Now quitting. Thank you, and please play again!\n");
      exit(0);
 }
```

Comment: It's `*character`, `character` is a `char *`.

Comment: Understandable. The OP was sloppy with naming too. :)

Comment: Thanks haccks. Now the program runs fluently and quits fine too.

Comment: @Nisarg; Your welcome.If this answer helped you then you may like to accept it.

Answer (score 3):

if you're trying to output one letter try replacing `printf("%s" , character)` with `printf("%c" , *character)`

Answer (score 2):

The printf function will print what it finds at the location provided and will ***stop printing when it finds a binary zero***. Your problem is here:

```
printf("%s", character);
```

Since the second element of the array is not zero it will keep printing until it happens to find a zero. In your case you were lucky and it found one before printing lots of garbage.

Comment: printf("%c", character);  There's an excellent reference here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Comment: I know that...but does the person reading your answer know that?  Just a suggestion on how to improve your answer.

Comment: I got the answer, but you provided a nice explanation for the printf function in the program. Thanks, Jay.

Comment: @Nisarg you should accept an answer that answers your question (no offense jay) because otherwise people having the same problem as you can get confused

Comment: @Lorenzo Donati Thanks, response should have been printf("%c", *character);

Answer (score 2):

Use `%c` as in `printf("%c", *character);` instead of `%s` in `printf("%s", character);`

You have a few logical mistakes in your code:

1) `char diceinput;` and then `scanf("%s", &diceinput);`, this is a big mistake, your program may crash as you don't have sufficient memory allocated (neither statically nor dynamically) for the input string. Use `char diceinput[5];` and `scanf("%s", diceinput);`

2) You have started indexing from `1`. (Pardon me if its intentional)

3) You are using `printf("%s", character);`, I will say its your luck that you are getting `"lrtete"` as output, i.e. it may not stop at `..te` and print some garbage characters after, because there is no explicit `\0` character at the end of character array.

Comment: "Use `%c` instead of `%s` in `printf("%s", character);`", not completely correct: `character` is a `char *`, it must be dereferenced as well.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati : Thanks for pointing that out, I pointed out his mistakes, but forgot mine. :-)

Comment: Thank you for providing a great explanation. Just to let you know, I started indexing from 1 on purpose for the sake of the user. Again, thanks.