# Exit with char in C

Tags: c, char, exit

I'm doing a command interpreter and one of the commands must have as result quiting from the program. When user inserts "q", the program should stop executing.

I've written this, but it seems very useless.

Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void exiting (char x){
if (x=='q') exit(0);

int main(){
char x;
scanf("%c", x);
exiting(x);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Format code and get it to compile

Comment: What, exactly, is your question?

Comment: Not understanding what the question is. Aside from the missing `}` at the end of `exiting`, there doesn't appear to be any issue. (ETA: and the fact that you should use `&x` instead of `x`)

Comment: `scanf("%c", x);` should be `scanf(" %c", &x);`.

Comment: Calling `exit(0)` is a [perfectly reasonable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425167/use-of-exit-function) way to halt program execution, but you might want to at least print out to the user that the program is halting because they typed the exit command first.

Comment: In the current form, your program will either `exit(0)`or `return 0;`which is the same (for all practical purposes)

Comment: @DrKoch In the current form, it will not compile.

Comment: @zenith Well, while reading all the comments I applied (mentally) all necessary patches before writing my comment ;)

Comment: @wolfPack88 Thank you. I was distracted. Now it compiles and it is working.

Comment: @cooper , I've rolled-back your edits as it made my answer, as well as, many of the comments above meaningless. BTW, Remove `else main()` from your edited code.

Comment: @CoolGuy Thank you very much for your answer. Just tell me... Why should I remove else main() ? It actually seems "not elegant", but I verified that if I do not put that part of the code, any letter can quit the program, isn't that so?

Comment: @cooper , Calling `main()` recursively is a bad idea. The better way would be to use a `do...while` loop. Yes, any letter can quit the program but I am assuming that you will add more code in the program soon.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void exiting (char x){
    if (x=='q') exit(0);
}

int main(){
    char x;
    scanf("%c", &x); //scanf requires a pointer since it's the only C way to change a value of a variable within a function
    exiting(x);
    return 0;
}
```

Or, if you want your program to run until you press 'q', that would be the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char x;
    do
    {
    scanf("%c", &x);
    }while(x != 'q');
}
```

Comment: It should be OK now :)

Comment: Nope. The signature of `main` should be `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%c", x);
```

Should be

```
scanf("%c", &x);
```

Because `scanf` with `%c` expects an argument of type `char*`. You provide the argument `x`, which is a `char` and thus, gives the value of `x`(which is garbage as `x` isn't initialized) as the second argument instead of giving the address of `x` for `scanf` to store the input. This invokes Undefined Behavior. `&` functions as the address-of operator and gives the address of its operand.

Also, you forgot to add `}` here:

```
void exiting (char x){
    if (x=='q') exit(0);
} //this
```